# Sphinx4 StreamSpeechRecognizer In Real Time

Tags: java, audio, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I'm trying to record audio at a client, send it to a "server," and then use speech-to-text at the "server" with Sphinx4. My code:

```
public class SoundModifier implements Runnable
{

    private static final String ACOUSTIC_MODEL = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us";
    private static final String DICTIONARY_PATH = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict";
    private static final String GRAMMAR_PATH = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/demo/dialog/";
    private static final String LANGUAGE_MODEL = "resource:/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin";
    // other unrelated stuff
    public SoundModifier(ConcurrentLinkedQueue inputQueue, ConcurrentLinkedQueue outputQueue, String saveFolder) throws IOException
    {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.setAcousticModelPath(ACOUSTIC_MODEL);
        configuration.setDictionaryPath(DICTIONARY_PATH);
        configuration.setLanguageModelPath(LANGUAGE_MODEL);
        configuration.setSampleRate(16000);
        recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);
        // other unrelated stuff
    }
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        var now = ZonedDateTime.now();
        while(running)
        {
            while (inputQueue.size() > 0)
            {
                byte[] chunk = (byte[]) inputQueue.poll();
                byte[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(chunk, chunk.length);
                try
                {
                    getText(copy);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    Logger.getLogger(SoundModifier.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                recordBytes.write(copy, 0, copy.length);
                byte[][] send = new byte[][]{"audio".getBytes(), copy };
                outputQueue.add(send);
            }
        }
        String time = now.getYear() + "-" + now.getMonthValue() + "-" + now.getDayOfMonth() + "--" + now.getHour() + "-" + now.getMinute() + "-" + now.getSecond();
        String filename = saveFolder + time + " SoundModifier.wav";
        File file = new File(filename);
        try
        {
            save(file);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(SoundRecorder.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, null, ex);
        }
    }
    private ArrayList<WordResult> getText(byte[] input) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<WordResult> utteredWords = new ArrayList<>();
        stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(input);
        recognizer.startRecognition(stream);
    SpeechResult result;
        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null)
        {
//            var words = result.getWords();
//            System.out.println("words: " + words);
//            utteredWords.addAll(words);
        System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n", result.getHypothesis());
            serverFrame.setASRText(result.getHypothesis());
    }
    recognizer.stopRecognition();
        return utteredWords;
    }

    public void save(File wavFile) throws IOException
    {
        byte[] audioData = recordBytes.toByteArray();
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
        try (AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(bais, format, audioData.length / format.getFrameSize()))
        {
            AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, wavFile);
        }
        recordBytes.close();
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "recordBytes close");
    }


}
```

This produces the following output:

```
11:23:33.703 INFO trieNgramModel       LM Cache Size: 0 Hits: 0 Misses: 0
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime   
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Load Dictionary      46      0.0350s   0.0340s   0.0740s   0.0415s   1.9100s   
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Load AM              1       0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Frontend             184     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0000s   0.0090s   
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Load LM              46      0.2640s   0.2320s   0.3450s   0.2699s   12.4150s  
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Score                184     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0000s   0.0090s   
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Prune                460     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Grow                 644     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0001s   0.0380s   
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker         Compile              46      0.3450s   0.2990s   0.6200s   0.3422s   15.7400s  
11:23:33.703 INFO speedTracker            Total Time Audio: 5.89s  Proc: 0.03s 0.00 X real time
11:23:33.703 INFO memoryTracker           Mem  Total: 1186.00 Mb  Free: 689.00 Mb
11:23:33.703 INFO memoryTracker           Used: This: 497.00 Mb  Avg: 657.31 Mb  Max: 1468.03 Mb
11:23:33.703 INFO dictionary           Loading dictionary from: jar:file:/C:/Users/???/.m2/repository/de/sciss/sphinx4-data/1.0.0/sphinx4-data-1.0.0.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict
11:23:33.743 INFO dictionary           Loading filler dictionary from: jar:file:/C:/Users/???/.m2/repository/de/sciss/sphinx4-data/1.0.0/sphinx4-data-1.0.0.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us/noisedict
11:23:33.743 INFO trieNgramModel       Loading n-gram language model from: jar:file:/C:/Users/???/.m2/repository/de/sciss/sphinx4-data/1.0.0/sphinx4-data-1.0.0.jar!/edu/cmu/sphinx/models/en-us/en-us.lm.bin
11:23:33.902 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word '3-d'
11:23:33.903 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word '3-d'
11:23:33.903 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adjustors'
11:23:33.904 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adjustors'
11:23:33.904 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adulyadej'
11:23:33.904 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adulyadej'
11:23:33.915 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'chloroflourocarbons'
11:23:33.915 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'chloroflourocarbons'
11:23:33.925 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'déjà'
11:23:33.925 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'déjà'
11:23:33.940 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'iife'
11:23:33.940 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'iife'
11:23:33.952 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mm-hm'
11:23:33.952 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mm-hm'
11:23:33.952 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mm-hmm'
11:23:33.952 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mm-hmm'
11:23:33.952 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mmmm'
11:23:33.952 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mmmm'
11:23:33.954 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'ngo's'
11:23:33.954 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'ngo's'
11:23:33.956 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'occured'
11:23:33.956 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'occured'
11:23:33.956 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'offical'
11:23:33.956 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'offical'
11:23:33.956 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'officals'
11:23:33.956 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'officals'
11:23:33.963 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'port_au_prince'
11:23:33.963 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'port_au_prince'
11:23:33.963 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'possiblity'
11:23:33.963 WARNING trieNgramModel    The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'possiblity'
11:23:33.987 WARNING trieNgramModel    Dictionary is missing 15 words that are contained in the language model.
11:23:34.080 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'offical'
11:23:34.080 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mm-hm'
11:23:34.081 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adulyadej'
11:23:34.081 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'adjustors'
11:23:34.082 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mm-hmm'
11:23:34.082 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'ngo's'
11:23:34.082 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'officals'
11:23:34.083 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'chloroflourocarbons'
11:23:34.083 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word '3-d'
11:23:34.084 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'déjà'
11:23:34.085 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'port_au_prince'
11:23:34.086 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'mmmm'
11:23:34.086 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'iife'
11:23:34.089 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'possiblity'
11:23:34.090 INFO dictionary           The dictionary is missing a phonetic transcription for the word 'occured'
11:23:34.281 INFO lexTreeLinguist      Max CI Units 43
11:23:34.281 INFO lexTreeLinguist      Unit table size 79507
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime   
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Load Dictionary      47      0.0400s   0.0340s   0.0740s   0.0415s   1.9500s   
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Load AM              1       0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Frontend             184     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0000s   0.0090s   
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Load LM              47      0.2440s   0.2320s   0.3450s   0.2693s   12.6590s  
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Score                184     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0000s   0.0090s   
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Prune                460     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Grow                 644     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0001s   0.0380s   
11:23:34.281 INFO speedTracker         Compile              47      0.2940s   0.2940s   0.6200s   0.3411s   16.0340s  
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker            This  Time Audio: 0.13s  Proc: 0.00s  Speed: 0.00 X real time
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker            Total Time Audio: 6.02s  Proc: 0.03s 0.00 X real time
11:23:34.282 INFO memoryTracker           Mem  Total: 1186.00 Mb  Free: 301.00 Mb
11:23:34.282 INFO memoryTracker           Used: This: 885.00 Mb  Avg: 659.76 Mb  Max: 1468.03 Mb
11:23:34.282 INFO trieNgramModel       LM Cache Size: 0 Hits: 0 Misses: 0
Hypothesis: 
11:23:34.282 INFO trieNgramModel       LM Cache Size: 0 Hits: 0 Misses: 0
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         # ----------------------------- Timers----------------------------------------
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         # Name               Count   CurTime   MinTime   MaxTime   AvgTime   TotTime   
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Load Dictionary      47      0.0400s   0.0340s   0.0740s   0.0415s   1.9500s   
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Load AM              1       0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   0.8700s   
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Frontend             188     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0000s   0.0090s   
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Load LM              47      0.2440s   0.2320s   0.3450s   0.2693s   12.6590s  
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Score                188     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0000s   0.0090s   
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Prune                470     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0000s   
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Grow                 658     0.0000s   0.0000s   0.0030s   0.0001s   0.0380s   
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker         Compile              47      0.2940s   0.2940s   0.6200s   0.3411s   16.0340s  
11:23:34.282 INFO speedTracker            Total Time Audio: 6.02s  Proc: 0.03s 0.00 X real time
11:23:34.282 INFO memoryTracker           Mem  Total: 1186.00 Mb  Free: 301.00 Mb
11:23:34.282 INFO memoryTracker           Used: This: 885.00 Mb  Avg: 662.16 Mb  Max: 1468.03 Mb
```

This type of output repeats while I'm recording audio with the client (and goes longer than the recording time actually, even though it looks like the processing time is 0.03 seconds).

Audio format is defined elsewhere:

```
public class StaticAudioFormat
{
    private static final int channels = 1;
    private static final boolean signed = true;
    private static final boolean bigEndian = false;
    private static final float sampleRate = 16000;
    private static final int sampleSizeInBits = 16;


        /**
     * Defines a default audio format used to record
     */

    static AudioFormat getAudioFormat()
    {
        return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
    }

}
```

I can read the saved audio into Audacity after-the-fact and it sounds fine. I can transcribe the recorded file with:

```
        recognizer.startRecognition(new FileInputStream("???/2020-5-12--13-9-37 SoundModifier.wav"));
        SpeechResult result = recognizer.getResult();
        recognizer.stopRecognition();
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
        while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
            System.out.println(result.getHypothesis());
        }
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------");
```

...and it correctly outputs what I said.

What do I need to do to get Sphinx4's StreamSpeechRecognizer to output text from speech in real time?

Edit: I'm on Windows, which may preclude some options.